# javascript break on first line

Tags: javascript, debugging, breakpoints

I'm currently using Firebug to debug web applications.

Typically, when we would debug an application, we must follow theses steps:

1. Find the relevant code in the debugger's code view pane.
2. Set a breakpoint where we think interesting things may occur.
3. Reload the page in the browser OR click on a button (or other component) which is controlled by JavaScript.

My question: is there a way to tell the debugger to break on the next JavaScript line to be executed ?

In other words: I load my page, I set an option in my debugger, I click on a button (which is controlled by JavaScript) and my debugger will break on the line which is executed (the one who catches the button click).

Typically, in an application with multiple scripts where is is difficult to find where the interesting thing is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know about Firebug, but the Chrome developer tools can do that (kind of): https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en ("Break before JavaScript event listener is fired") .

Comment: thanks, in chrome I can add a "Event Listener Breakpoints" on the "Mouse" > "click" event. Is there a way to break when I click on a button ? Because by adding the "click" listener, it breaks on any click.

Comment: *"Because by adding the "click" listener, it breaks on any click."* Only if there is an event handler. If you click on an element and there is no event handler set, nothing will happen.

Comment: nope, I can click anywhere on the page and it breaks. I would like only when i clicked on a specific button (or another component) :)

Answer (score 1):

The debugger doesnt work the you wanted it to be. In Chrome dev tools, generic breakpoints are just generic all rules on all corresponding elements!
To debug a click in a certain Button you need to find listener that handles click event on your button particularly. Locate the listener script and add a breakpoint and work frim there.

Comment: thanks for the response.I'm surprised that there is no possibility to break on the click on a button without manually adding the breakpoint on the listener.

Comment: I totally understand. I am sure you will adapt quickly with the way dev tools work. Good luck.

Comment: @Kjnokeer, there is a possibility, you have to switch to the tab "Sources" and then find "Event Listener Breakpoints" and click on "Mouse" -> "Click". You are welcome.